# Pandas parse xlxs to csv - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas

```
for filename in mylist:
     os.chdir(expanduser("~//Desktop/"+changes)) #change direction to find the xcel-files
     df = pd.read_excel(filename, sep=";", encoding = "utf-8",header= 0)
     files = filename[:-5] #extract filename without .xlxs
     #Missing direction?
     df.to_csv("/"+batchname+"/BatchINPUT/"+files+".csv", sep=";", index = False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

The error I receive is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/2020-03-06 NEX BATCH/BatchINPUT/2018-01-24, MASTER, Generic, handyreperatur.csv'
```

I think its because I use the files in a certain folder on my desktop and then want to copy it in a different folders subfolder on my desktop.

To give you a beter view on it. 
Read-Excel: Desktop -> Changes(folder)
Write csv: Desktop -> BATCH -> BatchINPUT

Before I create a batch with filenames. Create a folder with two different subfolder. And use todays date for naming the BATCH-folder on my desktop.

Any ideas on how to write the excel-files as csv-file in a proper way to my target-folder?

Comment: It does not matter which directory you read or write to using pandas as long as you have appropriate permissions. The issue here seems to be the file being not accessible. If you are searching in the current directory, you should precede the filename with './' or nothing at all. can you try that?

Comment: Also df.to_csv will not create sub directories. The subdirectories must already exist. for the file to be written there You can use os.makedirs to create the subdirectories before writing the csv file to that location

Comment: subdirectiories already exist. Just want to give path and file name for the to_csv

Comment: Have you tried modifying df.to_csv to './' instead of '/' to indicate the top of the directory?

Comment: Jesus..... it seems that I just needed to add the '.' before the first '/' in the to_csv function.......

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to say... good that it solved... '/' indicates the root folder.

Comment: Posted the same as an answer so others can use it as well!

Answer (score 0):

The directory location is being pointed to the root folder instead of the current directory.

Change this line:

```
df.to_csv("/"+batchname+"/BatchINPUT/"+files+".csv", sep=";", index = False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

to

```
df.to_csv("./"+batchname+"/BatchINPUT/"+files+".csv", sep=";", index = False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

`"./"` indicates current file location.